# Ajax get value from php

Tags: php, ajax

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#diklat").change(function(){
            var diklat = $("#diklat").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "function.php",
                data: {'action': 'diklat'},
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#angkatan").html(msg);
                }
            });
          });
```

PHP

```
    $get_action = $_GET['action'];
if($get_action=='diklat'){
        $diklat = $_GET['diklat'];
        $angkatan = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM batches WHERE IdMasterDiklat='$diklat' order by id");
        echo "<option>-- Pilih Angkatan --</option>";
        while($p = mysql_fetch_array($angkatan)){
            echo "<option value=\"".$p['id']."\">".$p['name']."</option>\n";
        }
    }
```

The value didnt include in my ajax, ajax only read echo. how to get that value

Comment: Use `$_GET['action']` instead `$_GET['diklat']`

Comment: in your js code data: {'action': 'diklat'}, should be data: {'action': diklat},

Comment: @vishwakarma09 nothing change

Comment: use the comment by @Saty too, the php variable should be $_GET['action'].Also, check if the query result is not false.

Comment: @Saty sure, i already add that in above. i think the problem in js

Comment: @vishwakarma09 the query is good. now ill try put diklat on action. but js didnt work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass 2 variables, one action and another id (diklat)

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#diklat").on('change', function(){
            var diklat = $("#diklat").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "function.php",
                data: {'action': 'diklat', 'diklat':diklat},
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#angkatan").html(msg);
                }
            });
          });
```

**PHP**

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';

if ($action == 'diklat')
{
    $diklat   = isset($_POST['diklat']) ? $_POST['diklat'] : '';
    $angkatan = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM batches WHERE IdMasterDiklat='$diklat' order by id");
    echo "<option>-- Pilih Angkatan --</option>";
    while($p = mysql_fetch_array($angkatan))
    {
        echo "<option value=\"".$p['id']."\">".$p['name']."</option>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: also try to use mysqli instead mysql, mysql is deprecated in future PHP versions

Answer (score 1):

You have written `data: {'action': 'diklat'}` but it should dilkat without quotes as its variable so in php you will get value in `$_GET['action']`.

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#diklat").change(function(){
            var diklat = $("#diklat").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "function.php",
                data: {'action': diklat},
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#angkatan").html(msg);
                }
            });
          });
```

**PHP**

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'diklat'){
    $diklat = $_GET['action'];
    $angkatan = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM batches WHERE IdMasterDiklat='$diklat' order by id");
    echo "<option>-- Pilih Angkatan --</option>";
    while($p = mysql_fetch_array($angkatan)){
        echo "<option value=\"".$p['id']."\">".$p['name']."</option>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

<del>For a GET request, to ask a PHP server, data should be URL-encoded (as you see [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), query string is just appended to the URL...) So tell `'data' : '?action=diklat'` ...</del>

**EDIT** : Jquery automatically converts object to Url-encoded query string... So It work with array ! I'm confusing with angular's $http...

And also, the parameter will be in `$_GET['action']` (because action is **parameter name**, and diklat the **value**... So PHP convert query string to associative array, with parameters names as keysn and values as values...